# nasm and ld: xxx not specified for Mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, assembly, gcc, nasm, ld

I tried to assemble a Hello World but ld is throwing me a couple of errors.

Hello World:

```
section .data
    msg db "Hello world",10  

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 13
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

nasm & ld:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.asm
ld main.o -o main
```

ld gives me these errors:

```
ld: warning: platform not specified
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: No platform min-version specified on command line
ld: warning: ignoring file main.o, building for -unknown but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
Undefined symbols for architecture unknown:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture unknown
```

I tried using nasm with macho64

```
nasm -f macho64 main.asm
```

and got the following errors from ld:

```
ld: warning: alignment (1) of atom '_start' is too small and may result in unaligned pointers 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `_main` instead of `_start` or specify entry point via `ld` command line argument. Note, the code is for linux and will not work on macos.

Comment: Those are Linux system call numbers, not MacOS.  Find a MacOS tutorial, don't try to port a Linux tutorial at the same time as learning the basics it's trying to teach you.